# Error "std::exception" in GRASS GIS via QGIS

Tags: qgis, mac, qgis-grass-plugin

Does anyone know what this error means? I am using the GRASS GIS plugin in QGIS and I have imported a road layer (vector) using v.in.ogr.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried loading the road layer into QGIS or Google Earth Pro? The road layer may be corrupt. By checking if it loads in other systems you can rule that possibility out.